# how to send mail with attachment which is byte array with java mail sender?

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

I want to send an email using java mail sender.I have byte array which I should send as a mail attachment.I have tried multiple ways but the attachment that is coming is not in readable format.Its coming as bytes.Below is the code I have tried.

```
public void sendMailWithAttachments(EmailContent emailContent,
            byte[] attachment) {
        try{
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new 
             MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

            mimeMessageHelper.setTo(emailContent.getTo());
            mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(emailContent.getFrom());
            mimeMessageHelper.setCc(emailContent.getCc());
            mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(emailContent.getSubject());


                final InputStreamSource attachmentSource = new ByteArrayResource(attachment);
                DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment, "application/pdf");
                mimeMessageHelper.addAttachment("testattachment", dataSource);



            emailSender.send(mimeMessageHelper.getMimeMessage());
            emailContent.setStatus(true);
        }catch(Exception e){    
            e.printstacktrace
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's coming as bytes"?  You're sending bytes, what did you expect to receive?  If you're really sending a pdf file, you probably want the file name to be "testattachment.pdf".

Comment: I expected it to convert to PDF and then attach it.. since I gave the type of the file @Bill Shannon

Comment: Uh, no.  The bytes already have to be in pdf format.  There's no data conversation happening.